# Why is the word「ござい」used in this sentence? 白紙でございって意味だ

Tags: meaning, words

This is a dialogue between 3 students.

> A: おまえきょうのテストどうした？
> B: へへ　まあな
> A：なんだよまあなって...できたんかよ？
> B：ばーか　このおれができるわけないだろ
> C: こいつのまあなはいつものとおり白紙で**ございって**意味だよ

As I understand it, the word 「ござる」 is in polite form. I think that, in this situation, the word 「ある」 would be more proper than the previous one.

Extra question: 「まあな」 used in this conversation means 'well', right?

Comment: まあな = a very non-emphatic “Yeah, I guess so” or “Yeah, it was ok”

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This ござい is not used to actually show respect. ～でござい is an abbreviated form of でございます, and is a fixed phrase commonly used by traditional Japanese street performers such as [チンドン屋](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chindon%27ya), [ガマの油売り](http://ameblo.jp/miyazakitei/entry-12087481344.html), and [南京玉すだれ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nankin_Tamasudare) performers to show something off and draw people's attention. Person C is imitating their way of speaking.

> ㋐《「ございます」の略》「ある」の意の丁寧語。**多く口上などで用いられた。**
>   「田舎者で―、冷え物で―」〈滑・浮世風呂・前〉 (from [goo辞書](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/78351/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%94%E3%81%96/))

I don't know the English equivalent of this, but basically this ござい sounds somewhat like "Look at this!" or "Behold!".

Of course a 白紙のテスト is usually a bad thing, but B here does not care for it. He seems to be even proud of giving in a blank paper, hence the expression 白紙でござい (≒hey look at this blank paper).